# Reading numbers from textfile into array

Tags: c++, arrays

I've been playing around with this but I've gotten nowhere.  I am trying to read a list of integers from a txt file into an array (1,2,3,...).  I know the amount of integers that will be read, 100, but I can't seem to populate the array.  Each time I run the code itself, it only stores a value of 0 for all 100 integers.  any thoughts?

```
//Reads the data from the text file
void readData(){
ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open("data.txt");

if (!inputFile){
    //error handling
    cout << "File can't be read!";
}
else{
    int a;
    while (inputFile >> a){
        int numbers;
        //Should loop through entire file, adding the index to the array
        for(int i=0; i<numbers; i++){
            DataFromFile [i] = {numbers};
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read  single integer from a istream you can do

```
int a;
inputFile >> a;
```

Which is what you do in your while loop.
The while is good in the sens that for each integer in the stream (in the file) you will execute the will's block

This `inputFile >> a` read the integer one at a time. if put into a test (if / while) the truth value would answer to the question "Has the value been read ?"

I dont get what you try to do with you `number` variable. As is is not initialized by you it lloks like it's value is `0` which ends up making the foor loop not run

If you want to read exactly `100` integer you could do

```
int *array = new int[100];
for (int i=0; i<100; ++i)
  inputFile >> array[i];
```

otherwise you could keep a counter

```
int value;
int counter = 0;
while(inputFile >> value && checksanity(counter))
{
    array[counter++] = value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The first method worked and now my program is up and running :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading `a` into your `numbers`, Change your code to this:

```
if (!inputFile){
    //error handling
    cout << "File can't be read!";
}
else{
    int a;
    while (inputFile >> a){
        //Should loop through entire file, adding the index to the array
        for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
            DataFromFile [i] = a; // fill array
        }
    }
}
```

If you are looping through the file, the array will be overwritten with the new number everytime. This is probably not what you intended to do. You probably wanted to fill out 100 locations with 100 different number? In that case, use the following code:

```
if (!inputFile){
    //error handling
    cout << "File can't be read!";
}
else{
    int i = 0;
    while (inputFile >> a){  // Whilst an integer is available to read
        DataFile[i] = a;   // Fill a location with it.
        i++;               // increment index pointer
    }
}
```